# AuthenticationClass needs duplicating with UrlVersioning - Luracast Restler

Tags: php, restler

I would like to have an authenitcation class and also have my APIS versioned without having to duplicate my security code.

I have setup restler and added the following to index.php;

```
Defaults::setProperty('useUrlBasedVersioning', true);
$r->addAuthenticationClass('MyOrg\\Security\\APIAuth');
```

I have then setup my authentication class within another folder outside of the public folder. It wasn't working on its own but I found due to using the UrlBased Versioning I had to repeat the class in the different namespaces.

e.g.

> MyOrd ---> Security ---> v1 ---> APIAuth.php
>
> MyOrd ---> Security ---> v2 ---> APIAuth.php

I don't want to have to do the above but more simple just have

> MyOrd ---> Security ---> APIAuth.php

I'm using Restler RC5, any guidance would be appreciated or is this a bug with Restler.

Also logged as issue with the restler project https://github.com/Luracast/Restler/issues/433

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just implement the `iProvideMultiVersionApi` and return the maximum version that is supported by the auth class, which in your case will be 2. See the example below

```
namespace MyOrg\Security;

use Luracast\Restler\iAuthenticate;
use Luracast\Restler\iProvideMultiVersionApi;

class Auth implements iAuthenticate, iProvideMultiVersionApi{

    public function __isAllowed(){
        return isset($_GET['api_key']) && $_GET['api_key'] =='allow';
    }

    public function __getWWWAuthenticateString(){
        return 'Query';
    }

    /**
     * Maximum api version supported by the api class
     * @return int
     */
    public static function __getMaximumSupportedVersion()
    {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked great thanks! I also found in your examples for UrlVersioning it mentions the interface , thanks for not telling me to just RTFM :).